# Password Protect app installation

Tags: android, password-protection

I want my App users to enter a password before they could actually install my app,

I have searched on this topic,but didn't get relevant details.
Any guidance will be helpful!

Thanks

Comment: You can possibly do the opposite: make them enter a password when they `launch` your app (hopefully once and for all).

Comment: Yeah, that's impossible.  The best you can do is either as @DerGolem suggests, or you can put the APK on a custom website rather than Google Play and require a password to access the website.  But that wouldn't prevent anyone who was given a copy from installing it.

Comment: thanks for reply....but I want to do this way..is there any way..(cause i am already having login password in app..but for some security concern i need in app installation as well

Comment: Or make your app paid: password = money. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on your way of distribution:
for example downloading the app of your repository: you can put you app in a rar with password, or you can put a dynamic download link that build this once you have entered the password.
Others solutions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8818011/4535278

Comment: interesting point but what if user shares the apk through bluetooth..it wont stop the other user to install it

Comment: if you give you app at the client you are giving the control of this. The only solution for not lost the control is make a [SaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service), if you have a server you can control  if some one is a legit user or not.